# How can I troubleshoot if I have an Android OS or hardware problem?

Tags: troubleshooting, asus-zenfone-2

I have an asus zenfone 2 laser and it has gone absolutely crazy. I have done a factory reset. The problem still exists.

It basically freezes, start taking screenshots...etc.

I was wondering if there is a way to troubleshoot an Android OS for software issues (or come to the conclusion that it is the phone itself that is not okay).

Comment: Try flashing stock firmware

Comment: This is quite difficult to do without access to other hardware for comparison, but you could try to flash a different ROM and see if the behavior stops.

Comment: I cant find anything official for Zenfone 2 laser ZE500KL, but nothing. I could and have only done factory reset so far. Although the bootloader is unlocked and I could flash a ROM, but then again: there is none for this device.

I'll try the stock firmware from the asus website. Let's see what happens then.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје hi there. Did you mean to use the firmware .zip with twrp and flash the firmware like that?

Comment: @Elysium No I didn't mean on custom rom and flashing via twrp, I meant on official firmware for you phone, made by manufacturer. You will find it on their website with instructions how to install.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје too late for that. :) 

Now I need to find the stock ROM, and I cant find that either. I'll never buy an ASUS phone. Ever again.

Comment: @Elysium [this, under firmware](https://www.asus.com/support/Download/39/1/0/20/KsY29RCpsJ2bea9O/32/) or maybe [this](http://www.asus-zenfone.com/2016/05/romandroid-60-asus-zenfone-2-laser-ze500kl-marshmallow.html?m=1)?  I am not sure about second link...

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје I have tried Smoothified Stock ROM [Z00L, Z00E]. It does the same things. Randomly starts freezing. Wont let me pull down the notification bar...etc. Either the sensors are dying or there is a bug that is now rooted into the OS or something. No clue. :)

Comment: @Elysium that is still custom ROM - re-worked stock but still custom. Try the stock firmware from asus site, if that give same results than it is most likely to be a hardware problem.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје Ok. I'll go for it. Do you know how I could lock the bootloader? I might need to take back to the store and unlocking the bootloader was not a good idea.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје I cant flash from the firmware on the asus website. It days "error in executing updater binary zip...."

Comment: Are you trying to flash stock firmware from twrp/cwm recovery? You don't flash stock firmware from recovery you do it from 'download mode' or via software on PC.